# *That is/those are* my rifle and the bullets

Tags: pronouns

- Which is correct?
- My research: I found a lot of questions related to using *that* and *those*, but none of those were about what I'm trying to find out. Then I found information about those in Cambridge Dictionary, but it didn't answer my question,. That is why this question occurred.

1. That is my rifle and the bullets
2. Those are my rifle and the bullets

Answer (score 1):

Apply the principle of ["proximity agreement"...](https://www.thoughtco.com/proximity-agreement-grammar-1691697)

> ***This is** my father and my brothers*
> because "father" is singular.

> ***These are** my brothers and my father*
> because "brothers" is plural.

Comment: So far so good. Hence we have "*That is my rifle and bullets*" and "*Those are my bullets and rifle*".  But there is a contextual aspect that needs to be covered too. "*What's that in the corner?*" may refer to the collection (singular) of things in the corner. Hence the reply "*That is my bullets and rifle*".

Comment: But equally, *What're they in the corner?* "primes" for the reply ***Those are** my bullets and rifle.* Annd although it's not exactly on a par with [***horses and coach***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horses+and+coach%2Ccoach+and+horses&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), the sequence [***bullets and rifle***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bullets+and+rifle%2Crifle+and+bullets&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) is definitely "second best".

Comment: I agree with you. I hope the questioner finds our discussion helpful.

Comment: It's quietly demonstrated in the answer and discussion, but I think it's worth pointing out to the questioner that "bullets" doesn't need a definite article in the sample sentence(s).

Comment: 'That is the crew and passengers'? 'Crew': formally singular; notionally plural (usually). Often used with plural verb forms.

Answer (score 0):

When two nouns are joined by " and" we use a plural verb. In this case
Those are my rifle and the bullets is the correct sentence because the noun " rifle" and the noun" the bullets" are joined by conjunction "and"